# Where can I see the VSTS Project CreatedOn date?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Where can I see the VSTS Project CreatedOn date?

Is it possible to view the VSTS Project CreatedOn date?  VSTS offers an audit trail capability within the project (Code, Work, Build, Release, etc...), but we are unable to determine how to pull timeline specific information about the larger project:

When was the project created?
When was he project last modified? 
Who created the project?
etc...

Comment: What do you mean by "project"? Are you talking about team projects? Are you talking about source controlled items?

Comment: Daniel, thank you.  This is in reference to a Team Project.  The Team Project then contains:  CODE, WORK, BUILD/RELEASE, etc...

Answer (score 1):

- If you mean the **team project**, then you can see the `CreateOn`
  date from `History` tab:

  Navigate to the `specific team project` (Root repo) -> `Code` ->
  `File` -> `History`
- If you mean the source controlled projects, then just select the
  specific project under the root repository, then check the history.

At the end of the history list, the last record should be the one you needed, reference below screenshot.

Besides, you can also use below REST API to retrieve that (But seems you need to convert the time format):

```
POST https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{ProjectName}/_api/_versioncontrol/history?  

Content-Type: application/json

{"repositoryId":"","searchCriteria":"{\"itemPath\":\"$/0522TFVCScrum\",\"itemVersion\":\"T\",\"top\":50}"}
```

[image]

Comment: @Brendan Have you resolved the issue by above answer? any update?

Comment: this helps.  Thank you.